# Npm: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY on already installed package

Tags: typescript, npm

Why on earth am I getting an:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.6.2
```

when typescript@2.6.2 is installed?

```
> tsc -v
Version 2.6.2
```

I've installed `typescript` globally.

**EDIT**

`packages.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "ts-odatajs": "^4.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.0.32",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.1.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.16",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "ngc-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "~1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.7.1",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us the `package.json` file - at least the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` values.

Comment: I've just added them on post.

Answer (score 0):

In my Angular project I'm currently using `"@angular/xxx": "~5.0.0"` with `"typescript": "~2.4.0"` and I don't have this warning message.

I saw that in `5.1.1` the Angular team still uses `"typescript": "2.5.X"` ([link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.1.x/package.json#L103))  which may be the cause for your issue.

When I had such warnings in the past what worked for me was deleting the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and reinstalling the dependencies.